# How to combine two columns from the tail of a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am going to do is:

I have two columns, A and B, I need to add b to the tail position of A, anyone knows how to do that?

Original dataset:

```
A  B
----
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
5  0
```

What I need is:

```
A+B
----
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Comment: Did you try a UNION

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for letting me know, I did it and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT b FROM yourtable
```

But do note, datasets in SQL are implicitly unordered.

Unless you add another column, by which you can order the results, they're not added to the tail, they're just unioned into a new unordered set.

Comment: Thank you! I should be more familiar with those syntaxes.

Comment: Just FYI. You could include an ORDER BY at the end. With `UNION` or `UNION ALL` it'll sort the combined result.  Also when you use `UNION` it will remove duplicates, which often does an implicit sort (because it had to sort it to find the dups)

Comment: @RShi Accept the answer if the solution worked for you

Comment: @LukStorms - My point was that in the OP the data comes out as `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}`.  You can't ***guarantee*** that order, because the desire to get the `0` ***last*** can't be enforced by the data available.

Comment: @MatBailie I see, that 0 is at the end.  Oh well, he accepted yours so I guess that order didn't really matter. :)